# Compatibility between Datastax Ops Center and Dev Center and solutions

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

I am new to Cassandra. I installed Datastax Ops Center and Datastax Dev Center.

I know that these tools are not totaly compatible but I would like to know what is compatible and what is not?

Also, I would like to know if there exists solution to replace ops center for visualizing rows, columns, .. created with dev center in CQL!

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1):

The tools are almost entirely orthogonal. There is no reason you can't use both. OpsCenter is akin to a cluster management tool and DevCenter is more of a query/data exploration tool.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For example, when I add an element with devCenter in a base created with opsCenter, I can't see the new rows via opsCenter but i can request them through devCenter. I would like to know if there are other compatibility problems (for example : creating a base with ops and can't do some things with dev, and so on.)

Comment: The ability to view database information in obscene is being deprecated in opscenter